# Substituting for a .SET on the the command line

Tags: gcc, assembly, gnu-assembler, microblaze

I have some (Microblaze) assembly I need to build (via the GCC cross-assembler and linker) and execute many times with the (same) constants, currently fixed via

```
.SET
```

commands, changed each time.

Is there a way to automate the setting of in-assembly constants in this way and so avoid the dull task of resetting the code for each build?

Comment: Not sure I understand your question, what do you want to automate? But yes, if you have some source for the constants you can use external tools to generate a bunch of `.set` directives which you can then pass to the assembler before the files that reference them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the power of C pre-processor in your assembler files. This could be done simply changing file extension from `.s` to `.S` (capital S) on Unix-like platform or to `.sx` on Windows. Then using `gcc` instead of `gas` over these files will let C pre-processor first run through the source and then `gas` will be called automatically.

In this case you can use all regular pre-processor `#define`, `#ifdef`, etc. And of cause you can pass these defines from the command line with gcc's `-D` parameter.